# Query for manytomany relation (also return if empty)

Tags: mysql

I am building a popover, in which you can tick checkboxes. The options and choices are stored in a manytomany relationship inside a mysql database.

```
[ ] option A
[x] option B
[ ] option C
```

There are 3 tables. `sphotos`, `sphoto_feedback` and `sphoto_has_feedbacks`. sphoto_has_feedbacks stores a sphoto_id, a sphoto_feedback_id and a user_id, to reference the user that has submitted the voting.

```
sphoto
id | status_id | ...
1  | ...

sphoto_feedback
id | name     | ...
11 | Quality  |
12 | Creative |

sphoto_has_feedbacks
id | sphoto_id | sphoto_feedback_id | user_id
1  | 1         | 11                 | 9999
```

The Input is `user_id => 9999` and `sphoto_id => 1`. The desired output would be an array, which has all sphoto_feedback entrys, with a boolean variable, like this:

```
$output = [
   "0" => [
      "id" => 11,
      "name" => "Quality",
      "checked" => true
   ],
   "1" => [
      "id" => 12,
      "name" => "Creative",
      "checked" => false
   ]
]
```

It would look like this:

```
[x] Quality <-- stored in sphoto_feedback, also stored in sphoto_has_feedbacks with reference to user
[ ] Creative <-- stored in sphoto_feedback
```

I want to retrieve all the options from the database and check, if the user has already voted on the options or not.

I know how to do it in PHP with 2 querys, but I'd like to use just one query and would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: Could you show the table contents, the input value, and the desired result?

Comment: I edited the question and added the tables, the input values and the desired result

Comment: So I guess its a simple left join?? `SELECT * FROM sphoto_feedback LEFT JOIN sphoto_has_feedbacks ON sphoto_feedback.id = sphoto_has_feedbacks.statuses_photo_feedback_id`

Comment: Yes, it is. See my answer

Comment: You should put that in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to join the `sphoto_feedback` and `sphoto_has_feedback` tables, returning `NULL` for all the rows in the first table that don't have a match in the second table.

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, shf.id IS NOT NULL AS checked
FROM sphoto_feedback AS f
LEFT JOIN sphoto_has_feedback AS shf 
ON f.id = shf.sphoto_feedback_id
    AND shf.sphoto_id = 1 AND shf.user_id = 9999
```